# Stop init process using /var partition so I can umount it?

Tags: partitioning, init, unmount

I need to reduce the /var partition of a remote Ubuntu server so I can't use a live cd or anything similar.

I tried unmounting it but this happened

```
umount /var/
umount: /var: device is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

So I used lsof to see which processes were keeping the /var partition busy. There were several processes which I managed to stop except this one.

```
lsof /var/
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
init      1 root   13w   REG    8,3       68 2474064 /var/log/upstart/systemd-logind.log.1 (deleted)
```

The strange thing is that the file systemd-logind.log.1 doesn't exist

```
lsof /var/log/upstart/systemd-logind.log.1
lsof: status error on /var/log/upstart/systemd-logind.log.1: No such file or directory
```

So how can stop the init process from using my /var partition?

Answer (score 2):

## All commands can only be done through the local terminal

***Warning: executing this remotely (e.g. through SSH) will kill your current session and make it impossible to connect until you reboot the host!***

Put the system into single-user mode: `init 1`

You can see which processes are blocking files into the mount point can be so `lsof -f | grep "/var/"`

Stop service: `service dbus stop`

Unmount the directory `/var/`: `umount /var/`

All commands:

```
init 1
service dbus stop
umount /var/
```

Comment: While this may be the correct answer, please [improve its quality](/help/how-to-answer) by explaining what those commands are supposed to do.

Comment: ***WARNING***: Do NOT run this on a cloud-hosted VPS, e.g. AWS.  Doing so will stop all servers including the SSH daemon and lock you out until you reboot the server.

Comment: In this case, you can use a long dream
`Lsof -f | grep "/var/" `.
Then in turn disable the interfering service
`Service explams stop`
and finally unmount /var/
`Umount /var/`.
I really did not check whether hinder the summit `sshd`

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo service systemd-logind stop`.

This is the SystemD Login manager (run `man systemd-logind` for further info).

Don't forget, once you have finished with the filesystem, to start it with `sudo service systemd-logind start`.  If you forget, it won't prevent logins, but I imagine it will stop recording certain info.